# Sending vars back from php to AS3 at various times throughout script?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, communication

Gidday

I'm using some JSON at the end of a php script to send a status update back to AS3:

```
$send = array("error"=>"", "x"=>5);
$sendThis = json_encode($send);     
print $sendThis;    
exit();
```

No error means yay, and 5 means it's finished. It works fine, but I was wondering if there is a way to send back a 1, 2, 3 and a 4 at certain stages during the same script?

I tried

```
$send = array("error"=>"", "x"=>1);
$sendThis = json_encode($send);     
print $sendThis;
```

further up the script, but php saves it till the very end, and sends both $send arrays back at the same time, causing problems at the AS3 end.

I also tried using flush and ob_flush after print statement, with the same result.

Is there something else I can code to tell php to send something back midway through the script?

Thanks for taking a look

Comment: I'm not sure but it can be server configuration problem, in most cases each PHP script is running as different process or thread and will not send anything back to AS3, until entire script is completed. Tell more about your server.

Comment: Thanks Giga - I ended up just using an animated image that says 'Processing...' while the server is working. It will do the job for the time being.